# Trouble iterating through set

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I am attempting to implement a BFS and I can not figure out how to iterate through a set. The goal of this is to return ret which is the order of all verts I visited in the BFS. I believe the problem is in the for loop range as I'm pretty sure that is not how I would iterate through the set but am not sure. Also I was told to "not worry about CompareGameTreeNodeSharedPtr" in this project by my professor.

```
    struct GameTreeNode {
          // They hold the current state of the game board
          Board board;
          // and a set of children--each child is a "reachable" game state
          // a leaf GameTreeNode has an empty nextMoves set
          std::set<std::shared_ptr<GameTreeNode>, CompareGameTreeNodeSharedPtr> nextMoves;
        };
  


 std::list<Board> GameTree::bfs() const {
  list<Board> ret;
  map<shared_ptr<GameTreeNode>,int> visited;
  queue<shared_ptr<GameTreeNode> > q;
  q.push(root);
  ret.push_back(root->board);
  visited[root] = true;
  

  while(!q.empty()){
   
    shared_ptr<GameTreeNode> cur_node = q.front();
    q.pop();
    for (shared_ptr<GameTreeNode> node : cur_node->nextMoves){//fix me
    
      if(!visited[node]){
        ret.push_back(node->board);
       
        q.push(node);
        visited[node] = true;
      }
  }
  

  

 
}
return ret;
}
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: It is not entering the for loop

Comment: If you indent your code, you will be able to see the problem(s) more clearly.

Comment: Well, this code won't compile for several reasons and there's no way for us to know if the set actually has anything in it so... Maybe you should work on a [mcve].

Comment: @RetiredNinja I added a bracket so it will compile and it seems like the logic is right to me for a BFS but I am still not sure how exactly I would iterate through this set.

Comment: You would iterate through the set the way you are. If it isn't working then perhaps the set is empty and you have further debugging to do.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Hm that’s weird because whenever I add a print statement inside the for loop nothing is printed so it seemed like it never entered it. Do you think I should first try checking if the set is empty?

Comment: Check the `size()` of the set. If the loop is not entered then it is likely empty. https://ideone.com/Yyb916

Comment: @RetiredNinja You were right about the empty set. I'm not sure how to edit the code to account for that then.

Comment: It's already accounted for. If there's nothing in the set the loop doesn't execute. If you need to do something different in that case then you'll need to add that additional logic.

Comment: @List-PopSmoke *I'm not sure how to edit the code to account for that then* -- Programming is not like typing up a letter in a word processor, and moving a paragraph around or setting a different margin.  If there are logical bugs, you have to work them out and fix the code.  In some cases, the logic is flawed to the point of starting over with a new approach to the problem.